# Installation from a .c file

Tags: command-line, software-installation, compiling, gcc, c

I am trying to install a program that is installed from a single ANSI-C-file. However, the instructions that they give in the manual don't seem to work on Ubuntu. The manual reads:

> The source `solvate.c` is just one ANSI-C-file without any system-specific stuff, so it should compile right away with something like
>
> `cc -ansi -O -o solvate solvate.c -lm`
>
> It is tested under IRIX System V.4 (SGI), HP-UX, and Digital UNIX V3.2C; appropriate Makefiles are included. It should now also compile without warnings on any Linux/Unix platform.

When I run the C file using this command I get the following errors.

```
solvate.c: In function ‘read_next_pdbdata’:
solvate.c:469:17: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
fprintf(stderr,linestr);
             ^
solvate.c:474:17: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
fprintf(stderr,linestr);
```

[etc...]

Is there a slight modification that I could make to this command that would allow this C file to compile the program on Ubuntu?

Comment: Those are warnings and not errors, and valid warnings at that.

Comment: I don't know about that, but if I see `fprintf(stderr,linestr);`, I'd expect to see a warning.

Comment: . . . you can *suppress* the warning by adding `-Wno-format-security`; to actually *correct* the code, we'd need to see it. See for example [fprintf, error: format not a string literal and no format arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260409/fprintf-error-format-not-a-string-literal-and-no-format-arguments-werror-for)

Comment: Just because the documentation states it _should_ compile without warnings, does not mean it _will_ compile without warnings. Especially if the documentation was written 15 years ago, and the code has not been updated.

Comment: Reviewers: Since this question is about installing a program distributed in source-code form, *not* about software development, it seems on-topic to me. @steeldriver Maybe post an answer that mentions the build succeeded unless any actual errors occurred and includes those suggestions about the warning? I thought of posting an answer myself, but between your and muru's comments this is already answered so it's probably better for one of you to get the credit.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I am only beginning to learn code and now see that the warnings are coming from outdated code, not a failed installation. I will do as recommended by @steeldriver.